# ASP.net Web Forms Custom control automatically changes the ID of next control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have two custom controls. I have a Selector, that inherits CompositeControl, and a drop down that inherits from DropDownList. Below is a code snippet from my aspx page:

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="100%">                         
        <tr>
            <td class="a12bold" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;">contact:</td>
            <td>
                <div><cc:Selector id="SelectorID" runat="server" Width="300" /> </div>                                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="100%"> 
        <tr>
            <td class="a12bold" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;">Category:</td>
            <td><cm:DropDown id="dropDownID" runat="server"   Width="350px" AutoSelectSingleRow="true"></cm:DropDown></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

For Some reason when my selector is rendered, the second custom control ends up having two IDs. Below is the rendering of the second control:

```
        <td><select id="SelectorID" name="dropDownID" id="dropDownID" style="width:350px;">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
```

I have spent two days trying to resolve this. Things that I have done so far:

1. Debugging the RenderContents() override for my selector
2. Debugging the RenderContent() override for my drop down.
3. Checking for HTML syntax errors. (opening tags, closing tags)

Everything seems to be working fine in the server side, until the rendering, which puts two IDs for my second control. How can I find what the cause is?

Comment: please provide code for your selector control

Comment: @techspider Apologies for the delay. I finally found the solution. I posted the code snipped below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally Found the solution! The problem was that I was previously using AddAttributesToRender() inside my RenderContents():

```
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        AddAttributesToRender();

        string htmlOutput = getHtmlOutput();

        output.Write(htmlOutput);
    }
```

Once I removed AddAttributesToRender(), the duplicate ID issue was gone.